# What tractates have the most aggada?

Tags: agada-stories-legends

Recently, Daf Yomi completed Mesechet Taanis, which has a bunch of awesome Aggada. It got me thinking, which tractate has the most aggada? I know there may not be a perfect quantifiable number, but I think it’s an interesting idea to ballpark.

Comment: How do you define which sections are Aggadata?

Comment: The non-halachic teachings of the Gemara

Comment: Look into Chelek

Comment: @Dr. Shmuel   I’m not sure I Understand

Comment: Berachos, I think.

Comment: There are a few ways it's already been categorized. *Ein Yaakov* is a compilation of just Aggadeta; similarly the Maharsha's commentary distinguishes between Halacha and Aggadeta. So if you had the right text digitally and were handy with code, you could answer this one with mathematical precision.

Comment: Are you looking for the most words? Pages? The last perek in Sanhedrin (perek chelek) has a huge amount of words of aggadata but not sure if it’s the most dafim though